Can other people see that I'm watching a YouTube stream/chat?
I am looking at some YouTube live stream. The live chat is open but I haven't posted any messages. Can other people (e.g., other users in the chat or the livestream author) see that I'm watching the stream/chat?
Example of YouTube live stream and chat: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJQdHvff8Ik


Please disclose if you have cross-posted to other sites out of respect for other site members' time.

@Blindspots I agree with you that it would make more sense but in the past I have received shit for doing so (downvotes, negative comments, and edits removing such links). (not specific to WebApps, I forgot on which SE sites it was). And SE Inc doesn't care about: Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution. I typically crosspost on Reddit+Quora for several reasons, such as Roomba.

Yes, people can see it. There's a Participants button when you click the kebab menu in top right:

The contents of it are unclear, but I'm pretty sure it's something along the lines of the most active participants. As I didn't see my name on stream with lots of viewers but I noticed it on a very low viewers one, without typing anything.
You could just log out to ensure that you're not seen.
